# SonarQube how to get all issues using WebService API

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting issues by this url: http://myserver.url/api/issues/search

But i noticed that not all issues, that i can see in dashboard are presented in JSon response.

Why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could precise a little bit (SonarQube version, etc.).
Maybe [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) could help.
Regards.

Comment: This page is no longer exists.